# Turn query string to sub page

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I have a custom post type called event. The URL structure looks like this.

> http://my-url.com/events/2016/08/21/workshop

Where "workshop" is the name of the event. Right now the template will show different data depending on the query string. For example this URL:

> http://my-url.com/events/2016/08/21/workshop?sub=files

Will loop out some files. I'm adding the query string so i can do that in the same template.

```
<?php
$sub = isset( $_GET['sub'] ) ? $_GET['sub'] : null;
switch ( $sub ) {
    case "files":
        echo "TODO: Loop out files";
        break;
    case "participants":
        echo "TODO: Loop out participants";
        break;
    case "agenda":
        echo "TODO: Write out the agenda!";
        break;
        <!-- etc -->
}
?>
```

But i don't like this URL structure! I'd like the URL to be:

> http://my-url.com/events/2016/08/21/workshop/files

So that i in the "Event" template (`/workshop/`) can look at the URL structure instead of the query string. The problem is that adding `/files`to the URL will make wordpress look for a page that doesn't exist and give a 404.

Is it possible to do some URL wizardry so the template (and post data) of this url:

> http://my-url.com/events/2016/08/21/workshop/

Also kicks in with this URL:

> http://my-url.com/events/2016/08/21/workshop/agenda/

Comment: To clarify, you want URLs such as `http://web.site/events/2016/08/16/hello-world?sub=files`
`http://web.site/events/1999/12/31/new-years?sub=images` to strip `?sub=` and replace it with a `/` to be `2016/08/16/hello-world/files`?

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Nope, don't wanna use query strings at all. See "update 2"

Comment: I'm confused by your question then. From what I understand: your website is having pages with `.../events/2016/08/21/workshop?sub=files` but you want the structure to be `/events/2016/08/21/workshop/files` instead. Where `/files` is another page template? You're gonna have to clarify your question more. Since I'm not the only one not understanding it entirely.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Sorry for the confusion. Your assumption is almost exactly what i mean. Except the last part. I want `/files` to use the same template (and post object) as the "Event" (`/workshop/`). I have rewritten the post to clarify more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [end points](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). This is my final (but simplified) code. In functions i added this.

```
add_action('init', 'jbenjaminsson_add_endpoints');
function jbenjaminsson_add_endpoints()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'files', EP_PERMALINK );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'participants', EP_PERMALINK );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'agenda', EP_PERMALINK );
}

add_filter( 'request', 'jbenjaminsson_filter_request' );
function jbenjaminsson_filter_request( $vars )
{
    if( isset( $vars['files'] ) ) $vars['files'] = true;
    if( isset( $vars['participants'] ) ) $vars['participants'] = true;
    if( isset( $vars['agenda'] ) ) $vars['agenda'] = true;
    return $vars;
}
```

And on the template i did this:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'files' ) ) {
    get_template_part( '/template-parts/event', 'files' );
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'participants' ) ) {
    get_template_part( '/template-parts/event', 'participants' );
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'agenda' ) ) {
    get_template_part( '/template-parts/event', 'agenda' );
}
```

Comment: Need to change `EP_PERMALINK` to `EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES` if you're on a page (and maybe other cases) and make sure to re-save permalink settings.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your `functions.php`-

```
function the_dramatist_url_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_tag('%sub%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^events/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/?', 
        'index.php/events/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%?sub=$matches[1]', 
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'the_dramatist_url_rewrite', 10, 0);
```

The go to the permalinks page in the settings menu at dashboard and hit `Save Changes` button. Hope this is gonna help.

Comment: ps: the  `add_rewrite_rule` might need some fixing too

Comment: Sure. Go ahead. You can edit my answer or you can suggest me. :)

Comment: Since I don't fully understand the question  I don't want to do possible wrong edits ;-)  like if *files* is a static word or if it's for any file attachment or something else or how the current rewrite rules are constructed?  But hopefully OP can use your suggestions as a starting point and even explain it better for you.  PS: I noticed a missing `?` for `index.php` and then it's not clear what matches `$matches[1]`.

Comment: Sorry, i was a bit unclear. I updated my question. I don't to rewrite my query strings. I don't want to use them at all. Problem is; how do i make the template to be used when there is an extra step in the URL?